# Create Map using AutoMapper 6.1.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have two entity EF classes Region and Country.

```
public class Region
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; } 
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; } // FK
}
```

I want to map these entities to corresponding  ViewModels.

```
public class RegionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<int> Countries { get; set; }
}
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However in AutoMapper 6.1.1 Mapper does not contain definition for CreateMap.
`Mapper.CreateMap<Regin, RegionViewModel>()` 
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<RegionViewModel, Region>());   
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
Region target = mapper.Map<Region>(source as RegionViewModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class, to define your mapping profile:

```
public class MyMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MyMappingProfile()
    {
        // define your mapping here, for example:
        CreateMap<RegionViewModel, Region>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CountryViewModel, Country>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then in your application startup, initilize automapper using this profile, as an example, if you are using a console application, you can put the initialization in you Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile<MyMappingProfile>()); 
    // other initialization...
```

Or if you are using an Asp.Net MVC application, you can put the initialization in *Application_Start()* in *Global.asax*

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the #1 item in the official docs... thank you!